# Evaluate $\frac{0!}{4!}+\frac{1!}{5!}+\frac{2!}{6!}+\frac{3!}{7!}+\frac{4!}{8!}+\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, factorial

$$\frac{0!}{4!}+\frac{1!}{5!}+\frac{2!}{6!}+\frac{3!}{7!}+\frac{4!}{8!}+\frac{5!}{9!}+\frac{6!}{10!}+\cdots$$

This goes up to infinity. Trying finite cases may help.

**My Attempt**:It seems that it is going to be $\frac{1}{18}$. My calculations show that its going near $\frac{1}{18}$.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

An alternative approach to Behrouz' fine one through [Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). We have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n!}{(n+4)!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+5)}&=&\frac{1}{\Gamma(4)}\sum_{n\geq 0}B(4,n+1)\\&=&\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{n}(1-x)^3\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^2\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1}x^2\,dx = \frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{18}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

> With the same approach it is straightforward to check that:
>   $$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n!}{(n+k)!} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{(k-1)\cdot(k-1)!}}$$
>   for any $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$.

The same can be achieved by recognizing in the LHS a multiple of a telescopic series.

Comment: interesting +1..

Comment: Thanks please check my answer is it true?

Comment: I like this, but I should also say that this looks like mosquito-nuking compared to Behrouz's answer.

Comment: @J.M.: you are right, but in facts I originally gave my answer just as an alternative to Behrouz' one, as I told in my very first line.

Comment: How do you know $\sum_{n \geq 0} x^n(1-x)^3=(1-x)^2$ after you use the beta-gamma function relationship? May you please explain.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla: $\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ is a geometric series.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize you can pull the $(1-x)^3$ out the sum. Interesting answer.

Comment: hats off to you +1

Answer (score 38):

Write $$\begin{align} {\frac{n!}{(n+4)!}}&=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}=\\&=\frac{A}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}-\frac{B}{(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}\end{align}$$

which gives $(n+4)A-B(n+1)=1 \implies A=B=1/3$

Then we get a telescoping series:

$$\begin{align}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac{n!}{(n+4)!}}=\frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }\left({\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}}-\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}\right)=\frac{1}{18}\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks but I surly know the answer is 1\18. note that your first equation is false

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: You may want to show how to decompose that fraction manually. Anyone can do it with a computer algebra system, which is of no use if this question is to be done on an exam...

Comment: yes this can only performed witha calculator

Comment: I don't use calculator

Comment: @TahaAkbari. I can be done without a calculator (and I think it should be) but there is a process called fraction decomposition involved here. The fraction contains factors $(n+4),(n+3),(n+2)$ and $(n+1)$ and essentially a telescoping sum could be used here to arrive at the answer. The "work" is missing here....

Comment: Thanks please check my answer is it true?

Answer (score 15):

Just a tip; For natural number $n$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)\cdots(k+m)}=\frac{1}{m}\left(\frac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot \cdots\cdot m} -\frac{1}{(n+1)\cdot (n+2)\cdot \cdots\cdot (n+m)}\right) $$

Now, the given infinite sum is equal to

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k-1)!}{(k+3)!}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}$$

by plugging in $m=3$ to the tip, we would get

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}=\frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{1}{1\cdot2\cdot3} -\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\right)$$

Take limit, $n \to \infty$.
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}=\frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{1}{1\cdot2\cdot3} -\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{18}$$

---

How to decompose the fraction;
$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)\cdots(k+m)}=\frac{1}{m}\left(\frac{1}{k\cdot (k+1)\cdot \cdots\cdot (k+m-1)} -\frac{1}{(k+1)\cdot (k+2)\cdot \cdots\cdot (k+m)}\right)$$

Comment: what can I do with this equation?

Comment: Plug in $m=2$, and you can get what you want! (I'll edit my answer(

Comment: @TahaAkbari Patience!  Goodness ... :)

Comment: Done! It should be fine.

Comment: Thanks please check my answer is it true?

Comment: nice.........................+1

Answer (score 2):

$A=\frac{1}{4*6}+\frac{1}{10*12}+\frac{1}{18*20}+\frac{1}{28*30}+\frac{1}{40*42}+\frac{1}{54*56}...$

$2A=\frac{2}{4*6}+\frac{2}{10*12}+\frac{2}{18*20}+\frac{2}{28*30}+\frac{2}{40*42}+\frac{2}{54*56}...$

$2A=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{18}-\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{28}-\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{40}-\frac{1}{42}+\frac{1}{54}-\frac{1}{56}...$

Now I write the Negative fractions like this:

$$-\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}$$

$$-\frac{1}{12}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3}$$

$$-\frac{1}{20}=\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{4}$$

$$-\frac{1}{30}=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{5}$$

$$-\frac{1}{42}=\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{6}$$

$$-\frac{1}{56}=\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{7}$$

And do this up to infinity.The sum of all negative fractions are:

$\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{8}+...=-\frac{1}{2}$

Now we have:

$2A=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{28}+\frac{1}{40}+...$

$2A=-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{28}+\frac{1}{40}+...$

$2A=-\frac{1}{1*4}+\frac{1}{2*5}+\frac{1}{3*6}+\frac{1}{4*7}+\frac{1}{8*5}+...$

$6A=-\frac{3}{1*4}+\frac{3}{2*5}+\frac{3}{3*6}+\frac{3}{4*7}+\frac{3}{5*8}+...$

$6A=-1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{8}+...$

$6A=-1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}$

$6A=\frac{1}{3}$

$A=\frac{1}{18}$

Comment: Did you realize that your argument and Behrouz' one are the same?

Comment: no they are different is my sloutio correct???????????

Comment: Yes, your sloutio is correct.

Comment: thanks for your help.Whiche answe should I accept?

Comment: It seemmmms that if I have many answers I should choose the best and I think like you