# Evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(n^2)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm interested in a method of evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(n^2)!}$.

If there was a linear equation with leading coefficient $1$ in the denominator or a quadratic  with leading coefficient $1$  and a coefficient of $0$ on $x$ in the numerator I would've used partial fraction, or a method seen in this answer by Jack [Evaluate $\frac{0!}{4!}+\frac{1!}{5!}+\frac{2!}{6!}+\frac{3!}{7!}+\frac{4!}{8!}+\cdots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824603/evaluate-frac04-frac15-frac26-frac37-frac48/1824744#1824744). But those approaches don't seem to be working for this specific series.

Is it even possible to evaluate this to get a closed form?

Comment: Not really to me I have a factorial $(n^2)$, in that question there is no factorial of a quadratic. @Franky_GTH

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form. However the convergence is very fast.

Comment: Because the convergence is so rapid, the limit is apt to be a transcendental number.

Comment: @hardmath: The convergence is certainly fast enough to show that the number is irrational. However, one would need each term to be smaller than the square of the previous term (roughly) to imply transcendence, and that isn't the case here.

Comment: Some transformations can be made using [Gauß' multiplication formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussMultiplicationFormula.html) for $z=n$.

Comment: 1.08334986772601479942751....

Comment: @GregMartin What do you mean here? It is most definitely true here that $a_{n+1} \ll a_n^2$

Comment: @GregMartin This is in fact pretty easy to note with Stirling. We have that $$a_n^2 \sim \left(\frac{n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}}{n^{2n^2}e^{-n^2}\sqrt{2\pi n^2}}\right)^2 = e^{2n^2-2n} n^{-4n^2+2n-1}$$
$$a_{n+1} \sim \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}e^{-n-1}\sqrt{2\pi (n+1}}{{(n+1)^{2(n+1)^2}}e^{-(n+1)^2}\sqrt{2\pi (n+1)^2}}=e^{n (n + 1)} n^{-2 (n + 1)^2} (n + 1)^{n + 1/2}$$
We thus get that
$$\frac{a_n^2}{a_{n+1}} \sim e^{n^2 - 3n} n^{-2 n^2 + 6 n + 1} (n + 1)^{-n - 1/2}$$
Which [goes to zero very quickly](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bumtsvjcts).