# Closed form for infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(n+m)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, partial-fractions

Let $m$ be a positive integer.
Is there a closed form for the infinite series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(n+m)}$?

In the cases $m=1, 2$, one can use a partial fraction decomposition to make the sum telescope. However this seems to become much more difficult for larger $m$ (and I'm not sure whether it continues to telescope). I suspect there is a closed form, but I don't know how one would obtain it.

Comment: It still telescopes.

Comment: I couldn't find this question when I searched before posting it; apologies for the duplicate.

Comment: Here is another reference  that might be helpful. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824603/evaluate-frac04-frac15-frac26-frac37-frac48